# App crash while starting new activity after using fragmenttabhost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am writing an Android App, and I face a problem.  If a open a fragment with a fragmenttabhost which has two tabs (each tab can open a fragment), then I open another a fragment to start a new activity, the App will crash and show the message like this:

```
09-13 17:26:45.398: E/FragmentManager(5171): Failure saving state: active BlacklistFragment{3b3b94ed} has cleared index: -1
```

If I open a fragment without fragmenttabhost, then open a fragment to start a new activity, there is no such question.

Please anyone tell me the solution, thanks!

Comment: Please post some code so we can help you. Please also post full error message.